# MVC4 Model : Using a List<> as a Property

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a Model with a class like this

```
public class Feature
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}
```

and one like this:

```
public class Camera
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
}
```

in the Seed() method I do something like this:

```
context.Features.AddOrUpdate
    (
            f => f.Desc,
            new Feature { Desc = "PTZ" },
            new Feature { Desc = "AutoFocus" },
            new Feature { Desc = "AutoIris" },
            new Feature { Desc = "PoE" }
    );

context.Cameras.AddOrUpdate
    (
        c => c.Name,
        new Camera
        {
            ModelName = "P3301",
            Features = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Feature>()
            {
                context.Features.Where(f => f.Desc.Contains("PTZ")).First()
            }
        }
    );
context.Cameras.AddOrUpdate
    (
        c => c.Name,
        new Camera
        {
            ModelName = "P3301p",
            Features = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Feature>()
            {
                context.Features.Where(f => f.Desc.Contains("PoE")).First(),
                context.Features.Where(f => f.Desc.Contains("PTZ")).First()
            }
        }
    );
```

After running update-database I see the records in the Features and Cameras tables, but the Features table has a new Camera_ID field that contains a single Camera ID.  I was expecting a Feature_Camera table or something so that a feature could be crossed up with many different cams.

What am I missing here? How do I say that a camera can have a a collection of non-unique features?

Comment: I think, you mean `public class Camera` in the second code snippet, right?

Comment: oops... fixed in edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a many-to-many relationship between `Camera` and `Feature` either add a collection to `Feature`...

```
public List<Camera> Cameras { get; set; }
```

...or define the relationship with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Camera>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Features)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
    {
        m.ToTable("CameraFeatures");  // name of the link table
        m.MapLeftKey("CameraID");
        m.MapRightKey("FeatureID");
    });
```

If you don't do one of these changes EF will assume that the relationship is one-to-many resulting in a foreign key to `Camera` in the `Feature`s table.

Comment: Ok, not quite intuitive for me since I don't normally think of the Features as having Cameras, but I guess they really do when you look at it from the Features' point of view.  I'll certainly remember the reciprocal List<> solve.  THX!